# How to create border a part of string when click : Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I will create border a part of string when I click at first and last character in string. For example: "exampleString" I click at S and g and click some button after that screen will show border at "String"  in "exampleString" only.

In my code, I split string from table array to split array when I click at character it will call `handleClick()` for keep index (f is index of first char and l is index of last char). After click first and last character of string that I need, I will click create button then call create function for keep string in split array between f to l and then show the border of text on screen like this "exampleTexts". I click at T and s, so f=7 and l=11 then click create button. In create array is ["T","e","x","t","s"] like this. After that, it will show the border at "Texts" on screen.

Thank you so much for help me.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import '../App.css'

class create extends Component {

    handleClick(index) {
        if(c == 1) { this.state.f = index
                     c = c+1 }
        if(c == 2) { this.state.l = index 
                     c = 1 }

    handleCreate = () => {
        let s = []
        let j = 0
        for (let i = indexF; i <= indexL; i++) {
            s[j] = this.state.split[i]
            j= j+1
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.split && this.state.split.map((item, index) => {
                    return(
                        <span key={index} onClick={() => this.handleClick(index)}>{item}</span>
                    );
                })}
                <button onClick={this.handleCreate>create</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default create
```

Comment: Try this - https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-highlighter

Comment: Can I change highlight colour ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of `react-highlighter`,

```
import Highlight from 'react-highlighter';
```

```
<Highlight search="brown" matchClass="abc">The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</Highlight>
```

`matchClass` prop is to add class name to highlighted part of string. Using this class name you can change the styling of highlighted part,

```
.abc{
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-xcpw5o)

Comment: I can't use search in Highlight because I need to keep text be array like this ["e","x","a","m","p","l","e","T","e","x","t"]. When I use search="example", it can't highlight it. But if I use search="e", it can highlight at "e" in exampleText. Thank you so much :)